# How to properly assign a distinct variable in class without affecting the class variable it is based on [python]

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently trying to use python classes as some sort of subroutine.

I am trying to process an array (say 'temp'). The array 'temp' is based on array 'x'. However, when I make changes with array 'temp', the array 'x' also gets changed which is very weird. *I want to ask how I can create the temp array without affecting the x array.

Here is an example code that I have which shows this effect more clearly.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np

class TEST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.asarray([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
        
    def process(self):
        print(self.x)
        print("- "*5)
        
        temp = self.x
        temp[:,0] = temp[:,0] +10
        
        print(self.x)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asd = TEST()
    asd.process()
```

The output is

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [7 8 9]]
- - - - -
[[11  2  3]
 [14  5  6]
 [17  8  9]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has cool specifics. If you equate one array to another variable, then they will connect and there will be a problem like yours. You just assign this array to another variable. I suggest changing the line to:
temp = self.x.copy()
In this case, you create a copy of this array. Good luck)

Comment: Thank you for this. I just tried it and found it to work with lists and numpy arrays. I am just curious, how about when dealing with strings ? .copy doesn't seem to work when the variable is a string.

Comment: Once again, python is amazing) If you want to copy a string, then you need to do as you did) This is how it works, because strings are immutable)